# Access configuration values initiated in __init__.py from a view

Tags: python, flask, config

Here is my file structure:

```
myapp/
  __init__.py
  config.py    
  views/
    __init__.py
    view1.py
  templates/
  static/
```

I initiate the config values in `myapp/__init__.py` though I would like to access them from `view1.py`.

So say I have `app.config['SECRET_KEY']` I would like to type that and get the secret key in `view1.py` just like I would in `myapp/__init__.py`. When I try to use `app.config['SECRET_KEY']` I receive an error stating `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] is not defined`

How would I do import the config values? Thanks.

Comment: `from myapp import app; app.config['SECRET_KEY']`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name app`

Comment: So where do you create your Flask app object?

Comment: In the `myapp/__init__.py` like so: `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: You probably have other imports that import your other modules, including your views (something like `import views`) *before* you create `app = Flask(__name__)`. Can you include your `myapp/__init__.py` please so we can advice you how to avoid the circular import problems?

Comment: That was the problem, I initiated the Flask instance after importing the view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Flask App instance is created before importing the view into `myapp/__init__.py`, then use this for using config values in other views:

```
from myapp import app;
app.config['SECRET_KEY']
```

Comment: I tried this and received this error `ImportError: cannot import name app`

Comment: What is your current working directory (os.getcwd())?  You may need to specify some additional locations in your import.